# Laravel create table and relation

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, pivot-table, relationship

I create system for players.
I have the following 3 tables:

```
matches:
    - id
    - win_points
    - draw_points
    - lose_points

aways:
    - id
    - match_id
    - user_id
    - score

homes:
    - id
    - match_id
    - user_id
    - score
```

Now I have some problem with relations.
I can get user, get his aways,homes but I can't get then info about match.

I am thinking about pivot table for away_match and home_match but I don't know if it's good idea.

Comment: You don't need a pivot table. You already have a foreign key that you can use to create the relation, i.e. a *user* `hasMany()` aways and homes. https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many Don't forget to define the relation when building your migration: `$table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');` (see *Schema Builder* documentation for more details).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need any pivots.
in the Models Away and Home you can add the following function:

```
public function match(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Match::class);
}
```

Which will return the match of the Away/Home. Unlike in the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-inverse), i here used Match::class which only works if you set the namespace to App\Models and not just App.

from the user you can now get the match with this piece of code:

```
$match = $user->homes->find($homeId)->match;
```

(you said from your user you can get homes and aways, so i assume you already implemented a similar method in the User Model

```
public function homes(){
    return $this->hasMany(Home::class);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As upto my understanding, you can use the [Many to Many Relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) between `match` and `players` table.

You can consider your DB structure in this way:

```
players
    - id
    - name
    - ...

matches
    - id
    - name
    - ...

match_player
    - id
    - player_id
    - match_id
    - match_type (either - home match or away match)
    - win_points
    - lose_points
    - ...
```

The Model and relationships would be like:

```
class Player extends Model
{
   public function matches()
   {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Match::class, 'match_player')
                    ->withPivot(['match_type', 'win_points', 'lose_points']);
   }
}

class Match extends Model
{
   public function players()
   {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Player::class, 'match_player')
                    ->withPivot(['match_type', 'win_points', 'lose_points']);
   }
}
```

Hope this helps!